# facebook graph api post locale

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

i have problem with facebook graph api search post

I would like to use graph api search for all posts containing the word "ikea" in my country.
I use the locale parameter, but it does not work.

```
$search = $facebook->api('/search?q=ikea&type=post&lang=pl&limit=10&locale=pl_PL');
```

Do you know a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Accept-language" on your http header.